# SQL Spatial Subquery Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

Greetings Benevolent Gods of Stackoverflow,

I am presently struggling to get a spatially enabled query to work for a SQL assignment I am working on. The wording is as follows:

```
SELECT        PURCHASES.TotalPrice, STORES.GeoLocation, STORES.StoreName
FROM          MuffinShop
            join (SELECT SUM(PURCHASES.TotalPrice) AS StoreProfit, STORES.StoreName
FROM            PURCHASES INNER JOIN STORES ON PURCHASES.StoreID = STORES.StoreID
GROUP BY STORES.StoreName
HAVING        (SUM(PURCHASES.TotalPrice) > 600))
```

What I am trying to do with this query is perform a function query (like avg, sum etc) and get the spatial information back as well. Another example of this would be:

```
SELECT        STORES.StoreName, AVG(REVIEWS.Rating),Stores.Shape
FROM            REVIEWS CROSS JOIN
                         STORES
GROUP BY STORES.StoreName;
```

This returns a `Column 'STORES.Shape' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` error message.

I know I require a sub query to perform this task, I am just having endless trouble getting it to work. Any help at all would be wildly appreciated.

Comment: What is the task you intend to achieve? You just posted your attempt...

Comment: Your query is also malformed, muffinshop doesn't actually join on anything...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to point that out. The join matter is a mistake. What I am trying to achieve is to incorporate a function query (like sum , avg, count etc) and get it to return the spatial component as well. Another example would be the following: SELECT        STORES.StoreName, AVG(REVIEWS.Rating),Stores.Shape
FROM            REVIEWS CROSS JOIN
                         STORES
GROUP BY STORES.StoreName;

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question, I would tackle the first problem with the following logic:

1. List all the store names and their respective geolocations
2. Get the profit for each store

With that in mind, you need to use the `STORES` table as your base, then bolt the profit onto it through a sub query or an apply:

```
SELECT  s.StoreName
       ,s.GeoLocation
       ,p.StoreProfit
FROM    STORES s
        INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT  pu.StoreId
                           ,StoreProfit = SUM(pu.TotalPrice)
                    FROM    PURCHASES pu
                    GROUP BY pu.StoreID
                   ) p
            ON p.StoreID = s.StoreID;
```

This one is a little more efficient:

```
SELECT  s.StoreName
       ,s.GeoLocation
       ,profit.StoreProfit
FROM    STORES s
        CROSS APPLY (
                     SELECT StoreProfit = SUM(p.TotalPrice)
                     FROM   PURCHASES p
                     WHERE  p.StoreID = s.StoreID
                     GROUP BY p.StoreID
                    ) profit;
```

---

Now for the second part, the error that you are receiving tells you that you need to `GROUP BY` *all* columns in your select statement with the exception of your aggregate function(s).

In your second example, you are asking SQL to take an average rating for each store based on an ID, but you are also trying to return another column without including that inside the grouping. I will try to show you what you are asking SQL to do and where the issue lies with the following examples:

```
-- Data
Id | Rating | Shape
1  | 1      | Triangle
1  | 4      | Triangle
1  | 1      | Square
2  | 1      | Triangle
2  | 5      | Triangle
2  | 3      | Square
```

SQL Server, please give me the average rating for each store:

```
SELECT  Id, AVG(Rating)
FROM    Store
GROUP BY StoreId;

-- Result
Id | Avg(Rating)
1  | 2
2  | 3
```

SQL Server, please give me the average rating for each store and show its shape in the result (but don't group by it):

```
SELECT  Id, AVG(Rating), Shape
FROM    Store
GROUP BY StoreId;

-- Result
Id | Avg(Rating) | Shape
1  | 2           | Do I show Triangle or Square ...... ERROR!!!!
2  | 3           |
```

It needs to be told to get the average for each store and shape:

```
SELECT  Id, AVG(Rating), Shape
FROM    Store
GROUP BY StoreId, Shape;

-- Result
Id | Avg(Rating) | Shape
1  | 2.5         | Triangle
1  | 1           | Square
2  | 3           | Triangle
2  | 3           | Square
```

Answer (score 0):

As in any spatial query you need an idea of what your final geometry will be.  It looks like you are attempting to group by individual stores but delivering an average rating from the subquery. So if I'm reading it right you are just looking to get the stores shape info associated with the average ratings?

Query the stores table for the shape field and join the query you use to get the average rating

```
select a.shape
 b.*
from stores a inner join (your Average rating query with group by here) b
on a.StoreID = b.Storeid
```